# Does freeing an uninitialized pointer result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c, pointers, free

If you have a pointer that is not initialized and, by mistake, try to free it, is this going to result in undefined behavior?

Like:

```
int main(void){

    char *string;
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't "free a pointer". You free *memory*, and you indicate which memory you want to free with a pointer to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does freeing an uninitialized pointer result in undefined behavior?

Yes.

However, freeing a null pointer is well-defined.

From the C99 standard:

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or
>   `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the **behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because accessing **any** uninitialised variable provokes undefined behaviour.

This includes passing an uninitialise pointer to`free()`. This itself also includes the case where the uninitialise pointer "by accident" may have a value equal to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is undefined behavior.

The pointer passed to `free` should be a pointer to a valid object allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` or a null pointer.

From C99:

> (7.20.3.2p2) "If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does, since you should only `free()` a pointer that 1. is `NULL` or 2. you obtained via a call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.