# A Segmentation Fault occurs when calling free() on a null pointer

Tags: c, gcc, free, segmentation-fault

I'm observing a very strange behaviour in the following code.
Compiled as it is, everythig works as expected: the output is "This is a sample program.".

If I uncomment all commented lines, I get a segmentation fault in the first call to free().

In theory comments shouldn't change the behaviour, right? What is the problem here?

PS: I use gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141224 (prerelease) on Arch Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
        char *welcome;
//        int max;
//        int x;
        free(welcome);
        welcome = strdup("This will be discarded.");
        free(welcome);
        welcome = strdup("This is a sample program.\n");
        printf ("%s\n", welcome);
//        max = 80;
//        x = 1;
//        while ( x <= max ) {
//                int y;
//                y = 1 ;
//                while ( y <= x ) {
//                        printf ( "#" ) ;
//                        y = y + 1 ;
//                }
//                printf ( "\n" ) ;
//                x = x + 1 ;
//        }
        return 1 ;
}
```

Comment: If the test run worked fine for you, it's pure coincidence - you're trying to free a pointer with random contents (allocated on the stack).

Comment: IF you compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would have gotten some warning... and you could use the debugger...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In theory comments shouldn't change the behaviour, right? What is the problem here?

The problem is that it is not a `NULL` pointer as it has not been initialised so the call to `free()` is attempting to deallocate at a random address:

```
char *welcome;
//        int max;
//        int x;
free(welcome);
```

This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), from [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

> The behavior is undefined if ptr does not match a pointer returned earlier by malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), or aligned_alloc().

Comment: Can you explain also why it works if I comment out the rows between the `char*` declarement and the call to `free()` ?

Comment: @leonixyz, it is just chance that the program functions as you expected. With undefined behaviour anything can happen, including appearing to work.

Comment: @leonixyz, uninitialized local variables will contain "garbage" values from the stack and/or registers (depending on compiler optimization, architecture, etc).  Adding more local variables to a function just changes where the uninitiated variable is stored, and therefore it's "garbage" value.  In the cases where it works, free happens to be NULL, just by chance.

Answer (score 5):

Comments do not change the behavior of any well-defined code snippets. However, [`free`-ing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160776/does-freeing-an-uninitialized-pointer-result-in-undefined-behavior). When the compiler sees undefined behavior, it is free to do whatever it wants; whether that be a seg-fault or (more insidiously) appear to work fine.

Comment: So, the fact that after declaring the pointer I  declare also other variables could change the behaviour?

Comment: @leonixyz If you're using undefined behavior, it could change every time you run the program, or every time you compile it. Anything could happen. So yes, any trivial change to your code, or no change at all, could cause the behavior to change.

Answer (score 3):

The title of your question says "A Segmentation Fault occurs when calling free() on a null pointer" but you are not trying to free() a null pointer.  The first time you're calling free():

```
char *welcome;
free(welcome);
```

the variable `welcome` does not have a defined value.  C does NOT initialize variables when they are created.  If you had done this:

```
char *welcome = NULL;
free(welcome);
```

then it would have been fine because free() will ignore the NULL.